# How do I get router-view to render components inside another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Most examples I see out there, has `<router-view>` set up inside the main `App.vue` component but mine isn't like that.

I have another component called `<content>` in `App`. Inside `<content>`, I have various other components like `<skills>`, `<projects>` etc.

Right now, I'm toggling each of them using a `v-show` but now, I want to use routes.

Here's the template of my `App.vue`

```
  <div id="app">
    <img id="photo" src="../public/assets/IMG_3187.jpg">
    <Content msg="Divyanth Jayaraj"/>
    <site-footer></site-footer>
  </div>
```

Inside the `Content.vue`, the template looks like this. **Notice the commented tags.**

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
      UI/UX Consultant
    </p>
    <navbar @select='navigate($event)'></navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <!-- <intro v-show='this.navSelect == "Introduction"'></intro>
    <skills v-show='this.navSelect == "Skills"'></skills>
    <education v-show='this.navSelect == "Education"'></education>
    <projects v-show='this.navSelect == "Projects"'></projects>
    <faq v-show='this.navSelect == "FAQ"'></faq> -->
  </div>
```

The `<router-view>` is supposed to render each of my components but aren't. Just for reference, I set up `vue-router` **after** I built most of the project.

Just for reference, here's how I have my router set up.

This is `routes.js`

```
import Introduction from './components/introduction/introduction'
import Skills from './components/skills/skills'
import Projects from './components/projects/projects'
import Education from './components/education/education'
import FAQ from './components/FAQ/faq'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', redirect: '/Introduction'},
  { path: '/Introduction', name: 'Introduction', component: Introduction},
  { path: '/Skills', name: 'Skills', component: Skills},
  { path: '/Projects', name: 'Projects', component: Projects},
  { path: '/Education', name: 'Education', component: Education},
  { path: '/FAQ', name: 'FAQ', component: FAQ}
]
```

This is `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes.js'



Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is my `App.vue` although **this might not be relevant**

```
import Content from './components/content.vue'
import Footer from './components/site-footer.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Content,
    'site-footer' : Footer
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Right now, there's nothing rendering inside `<router-view>`. I'm not getting any errors either.

Comment: you forgot to `export default routes` in `routes.js`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested routes. I did not test your code for myself. However I guess it works if you change your code similar to following.

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", redirect: "/Introduction" },
  { path: "/contents", components: Content,
   children: [
    { path: "/Introduction", name: "Introduction", component: Introduction },
    { path: "/Skills", name: "Skills", component: Skills },
    { path: "/Projects", name: "Projects", component: Projects },
    { path: "/Education", name: "Education", component: Education },
    { path: "/FAQ", name: "FAQ", component: FAQ }
   ]
 }
];
```

And also add `<router-view>` to `App.vue` component.

I think [official documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html) also can helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

As [sovalina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541423/sovalina) mentioned, adding `export default routes` in `routes.js` fixed my problem.